# Scenic View in project Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How to run a Scenic View in the project Eclipse? Searches for me all the time and nothing can be found. I think I did everything as it is in the documentation and will not start.

Answer (score 0):

launch ScenicView as a java agent :

Add following to the VM arguments:
    `-javaagent:absolute/path/ScenicView.jar`

Specifying the hostname for the RMI server on the VM arguments will probably fix it too:
    `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.xxx`